# using a filter() with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I typed `dplyr:::filter_rows(data-frame, observation)` and the following error message showed :

```
Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x object 'tuberculosis' not found
i Input `..1` is `tuberculosis`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to SO.

`filter_rows()` is not an exported function of the dplyr package. You can simply use `filter()` to subset your data